# Aumentando tamanho de um TextView, de acordo com a quantidade de dados inseridos na mesma

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo um app, para trabalho de curso técnico, e estou com a seguinte situação:

Estou exibindo dados dentro de um *TextView*.
Só que chega um momento que o tamanho não é o suficiente. Observe as imagens.

Foto do Inicio do app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foto da *Activity* Relatório, onde eu exibo os dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, olha aonde eu tive que puxar o *ScrollView*, pra poder exibir tudo.
Eu não queria isso. Queria a tela do tamanho ajustado com o celular, o tamanho pequeno, e de acordo que eu fosse inserindo os dados no *TextView*, ele ir aumentando.
Caso não haja algum jeito de fazer, usando *TextView*, poderiam me ajudar ?

Answer (score 4):

Os atributos que determinam o tamanho de uma *View* são [android:layout_width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_width) e [android:layout_height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_height)

O seu valor pode ser uma dimensão fixa, expressa por um valor decimal, ou uma constante que define como o tamanho se ajusta automática.
As constantes são:

**match_parent** - A *view* deve ser tão grande quanto seu pai (menos o *padding*)
**fill_parent** - O mesmo que a anterior mas considerada obsoleta desde a *API Level 8*
**wrap_content** - A *view* deve ser grande o suficiente apenas para incluir o seu conteúdo (mais o *padding*).

Para que o seu *TextView* ajuste automaticamente a sua altura em função do comprimento do texto deverá declarar o seu *layout_height* como *wrap_content*.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar seu problema adicione um `scrollView` antes de tudo, como mostra o exemplo:

> Lembrando que após um `scrollView` so pode existir um elemento, por isso coloquei um `LinearLayout`, ai dentro deste `LinearLayout` você coloca seus elementos.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            // aqui coloque o conteúdo do sua Activity

       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode nesse caso fazer com `layout_weight` se quiser ocupar a tela toda, já que você tem diversas resoluções e tamanhos, no `layout_weight` você pode definir por porcentagem, ou então utiliza `linear_layout` mesmo sem definir a altura deixando com `layout_height="wrap_content"`.